# Can't connect HP DeskJet 3050a J610a over WPS to a new Wireless Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, printer

I have this nifty little inkjet printer from HP, but it's unable to connect to my new wireless router ASUS RT-N12 (quite a common one). The only way to connect the printer is via WPS. So, I've tried the button way, the PIN code way. None of them worked.

My previous router was some cheap TP-Link, that was 802.11n Lite. Everything worked perfectly there.

I've managed to connect it once, somehow, when I've put the router in the Legacy mode with "b/g Protection" (the router doesn't use 802.11n in this mode, I think.) The problem with that was, I had to turn off the WPA2 authentication and leave the router open for everybody. Not good.

Is there any other way to connect the printer to the router? The is no USB port on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only way to connect the printer is via WPS

I do not think that is true.  I owned several HP Wi-Fi enabled printers and I'm sure all of them provide the ability to manually input WPA2 credentials. Some can be done through built-in touch screen interface, some others must be done with a PC connected to printer through USB cable.

This is the link to HP Support site regarding Deskjet 3050A Wireless Setup: http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Deskjet-3050A-e-All-in-One-Printer-series---J6/4311836/model/5061081/document/c02722113/

So for 3050A it is the latter case.

To put it shortly, you have to use USB cable and input your SSID/pass from a PC. I think this is quite straightforward since the program is a Wizard-style guided setup, but if you found difficulty just leave something in the comment and SU Users may be able to help you.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! Well, in this world of planned obsolescence, I was quite ready to buy a new printer, which would definitely be a sad thing! Thanks for the suggestion again, I'll try it ASAP and report back! :)

Comment: That truly just worked, although the drivers could be more user friendly! :)